# Disabling particular Items in a Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a WinForms App and I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of disabling Combobox item without changing the SelectedIndex property -1 for all disabled values.

I have been googling and a lot of the solutions involve ASP.Net DropDownLists but this [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawmode%28VS.80%29.aspx) looks promising. I think I may have to build my own ComboBox control but before I re-invent the wheel I figure I would ask here if it was possible.

## **UPDATE**

Here is the final solution, thanks to Arif Eqbal:

```
//Add a Combobox to a form and name it comboBox1
//
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.comboBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
                this.comboBox1.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.comboBox1_DrawItem);
                this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.comboBox1.Items.Add("Test1");
                this.comboBox1.Items.Add("Test2");
                this.comboBox1.Items.Add("Test3");
                this.comboBox1.Items.Add("Test4");
                this.comboBox1.Items.Add("Test5");
                this.comboBox1.Items.Add("Test6");
                this.comboBox1.Items.Add("Test7");
            }

            Font myFont = new Font("Aerial", 10, FontStyle.Underline|FontStyle.Regular);
            Font myFont2 = new Font("Aerial", 10, FontStyle.Italic|FontStyle.Strikeout);

            private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Index == 1 || e.Index == 4 || e.Index == 5)//We are disabling item based on Index, you can have your logic here
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), myFont2, Brushes.LightSlateGray, e.Bounds);
                }
                else
                {
                    e.DrawBackground();
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), myFont, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds);
                    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
                }
            }

            void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1 || comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 4 || comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 5)
                    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ASP.NET != WinForms, don't look there. Extending the basic ComboBox isn't terribly hard (usually done to add checkboxes or icons or whatnot), but I don't think there is any such standard support.

Comment: The link you have mentioned is the way to go if you really want to give users a feel of the item being disabled. You might want to draw the text as grayed out, you might want to not show a selection backcolor and so on and of course user can still select that item so you would of course need to handle selectedIndexChanged and set the selectedIndex to -1. But it will be visually more suggestive to do the exercise.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this... Does it serve your purpose:

I assume you have a combobox called `ComboBox1` and you want to disable the second item i.e. an item with index 1.

Set the `DrawMode` property of the combobox to `OwnerDrawFixed` then handle these two events as shown below:

```
Font myFont = new Font("Aerial", 10, FontStyle.Regular);

private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{        
    if (e.Index == 1) //We are disabling item based on Index, you can have your logic here
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), myFont, Brushes.LightGray, e.Bounds);
    }
    else
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), myFont, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
} 

void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Here's my answer based 100% on Arif Eqbal's.
The improvements are:

- reuse the `Font` from the ComboBox instead of creating new ones (so that if you change it in the designer, you won't have to update the code)
- reuse the default `SystemBrushes` (so it should match your theme ; it won't work if you manually change the colors used in the ComboBox though)
- for the disabled items I had to redraw the background, else each time the grayed items are redrawn, their color get closer and closer to black
- create a dedicated `IsItemDisabled` method to avoid copy/paste

---

```
// Don't forget to change DrawMode, else the DrawItem event won't be called.
// this.comboBox1.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;

private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;

    if (IsItemDisabled(e.Index))
    {
        // NOTE we must draw the background or else each time we hover over the text it will be redrawn and its color will get darker and darker.
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox.Items[e.Index].ToString(), comboBox.Font, SystemBrushes.GrayText, e.Bounds);
    }
    else
    {
        e.DrawBackground();

        // Using winwaed's advice for selected items:
        // Set the brush according to whether the item is selected or not
        Brush brush = ( (e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) > 0) ? SystemBrushes.HighlightText : SystemBrushes.ControlText;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox.Items[e.Index].ToString(), comboBox.Font, brush, e.Bounds);

        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
}

void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsItemDisabled(comboBox1.SelectedIndex))
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
}

bool IsItemDisabled(int index)
{
    // We are disabling item based on Index, you can have your logic here
    return index % 2 == 1;
}
```

Comment: @cool_php I haven't used that code for a while. Isn't the comment at the beginning of the code enough, ie using `OwnerDrawFixed`?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a further modification. The problem with the above solutions is that a selected item isn't visible because the font foreground and the background selection are both dark. Hence the font should be set according to the value of `e.State`:

```
    private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
        if (e.Index >= 0)
        {
            if (IsItemDisabled(e.Index))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox.Items[e.Index].ToString(), comboBox.Font, Brushes.LightSlateGray, e.Bounds);
            }
            else
            {
                e.DrawBackground();

                // Set the brush according to whether the item is selected or not
                Brush br = ( (e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) > 0) ? SystemBrushes.HighlightText : SystemBrushes.ControlText;

                e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBox.Items[e.Index].ToString(), comboBox.Font, br, e.Bounds);
                e.DrawFocusRectangle();
            }
        }
    }
```