# How to disable one of items in a combo box

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

How to disable one of the item in combo box collection values.

Comment: Checkout this link, the same question discussed there

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445125/disabling-particular-items-in-a-combobox