# Read Only View in WinForms

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

On a windows form, I added a combo box which is supposed to show all active items. However, when viewing an existing record which contains an item which has been deactivated, the item is not loading into the combo box, so it's not being displayed.

How can I have the combo box show the item, but not allow it to be selected for new or other records?

Comment: Can't you change the SelectedIndex, then set Enabled to false?

Comment: I need to be able to select active ones from the list, I only don't want the inactive items to be selectable.

Comment: Right, so you want to disable individual items in the combo box?

Comment: Why don't you just not show the inactive items in the combo box if the "box which is supposed to show all active items"

Comment: Yes. I am actually using DevExpress Lookup binded to a list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling particular Items in a Combobox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445125/disabling-particular-items-in-a-combobox)

Answer (score -1):

How about handling the Selecting event and cancel selection if the row is inactive?